# Edit just before final close-vote bypasses re-open queue

Tags: feature-request, vote-to-close, closed-questions, reopen-closed

Please follow this sequence of events:

1. User posts question.
2. 1-2 people vote to close the question (Probably downvoted too).
3. OP edits the question to properly meet guidelines.
4. The people who voted to close the question move on and don't review the edit(s).
5. OP makes a big edit **just prior to the final close vote** which brings the question up to proper standard.
6. A third person, now seeing that the question has 2 votes to close, for whatever reason submits the final vote to close.
7. The final close vote is cast but since OP edited just before the final close-vote, it never enters the re-open queue.

The obvious problem is that the question doesn't get a proper review and votes become permanent. There maybe other issues relating to confirming biases (See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399666/hide-up-down-votes-close-votes-on-unanswered-questions)) preventing edits from mattering but this is the most obvious one I can see, stepping through the problem.

Case-in-point: [Hide Close Votes on unanswered questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/399666/hide-close-votes-on-unanswered-questions) . My question was closed because it was a duplicate. However, I had edited it seconds before it was closed. It will not enter the queue. If I were to edit it again to enter the queue, the reviewers will not see the relevant changes that were made. Say, if I were to add a period or anything just to get it into the queue. It won't be obvious that I had done anything meaningful.

This also appears to happen if the question is closed while you're in the process of editing it.

Suggestion: Send to the review queue if it's been edited within a certain time-frame of being closed. Also possibly notify close voters of all edits.

Comment: Questions closed that are edited are sent to the reopen queue, so OP's rage can be ignored

Comment: @SterlingArcher Where's the reopen queue? There must be something wrong with it because I know this happens where a question made valid just never comes back. One can take the time to really overtly ensure the question is made good. I'm sure I could dig up some questions that fit this profile.

Comment: I stopped reading at 'We know this happens':(

Comment: @MartinJames We do know confirmation bias happens. We're human.

Comment: Question is now purely about a specific site malfunction after edits. Downvotes will keep coming though, np. That's is a separate issue: Showing up/down votes on unanswered questions is a bad idea due to aforementioned confirmation bias. Humans are terrible about being impartial in a group.

Comment: @xendi yes, it happens, in general.  What I am not convinced by is your claim that it's a problem that needs to be addressed on SO.  Many curators have considerable experience and technical/scientific training and are all too familiar with such cognitive rabbit-holes.  They have spent years trying to avoid misinterpreting evidence during testing/debugging.  Its not a problem that requires action.

Comment: @xendi could you please clarify what exactly you requesting as feature? "people should pay attention"? "every edited post should go to re-open queue"?

Comment: 'I believe I've experienced this a few times now, which means many must have'...sounds like a cognitive bias to me:)

Comment: I mean, I'm not saying that your scenario does not happen, I am saying that it does not happen often enough to warrant action.  There is surely a desire amongst curators to get the bad questions closed ASAP to avoid bad answers, and I'm concerned that measures to mitigate your issue may adversely affect others:(

Comment: "My question was closed because it was a duplicate. However, I had edited it seconds before it was closed." Now you're just flat-out lying. I can clearly look at the [timeline](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/399666/timeline) and see that it was closed four minutes before you edited it.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Are you hostile to someone questioning the system or something? In the case of the one I linked, it so happens that it got closed while I was in the process of editing it. No matter though. It was edited to be made good and still it's closed, where it will remain. I think the same problem happened in that case too, that it didn't make it into the queue because I started editing it before it was closed.

Comment: There you go @JohnMontgomery . That case was added to the question.

Comment: I think it's reasonable to expect people to challenge false statements, xendi.  Especially when you're combative about it; you've already written off constructive discussion, so there's not much incentive in attempting to reason with you about it.

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps there's a bit of hyperbole in points 6. and 7., but we often do see the earlier points that you make occurring, and for this reason there is a re-open review queue that automatically gets alerted as soon as the original poster edits their question after it has been closed.

I think that the best way for the original poster to prevent this from happening is to be attentive to action on their question as soon as it happens rather than the all too common, "post it and forget it" behavior that we see. If they respond quickly to comments and close-votes, they're more likely to catch the original close-voters before they lose attention to the question and perhaps alter their response to the question, even retracting down-votes and close-votes.

Comment: Since there's a re-open queue I was unaware of, I of course will grant those related points. Something still must be ineffective about the process though, in my experience. Whenever I get a downvote or close vote, I frantically work to fix it: Edit upon edit, addressing comments, etc. There are times (Not all) where it just doesn't matter. It's as though the weight of bias is just too much to overcome regardless of what the question has become. I know there are also times where I've deleted the question after it was closed, despite having made the necessary edits.

Comment: I think what's happening is the question is being closed right after making the necessary edits. Then the question never enters this re-open queue.

Comment: Literally the entire thing is hyperbole, filled with completely unjustified assumptions. The ending just turns it into a borderline rant. We have plenty of systems in place for re-opening improved questions. This is a complaint in search of a problem.

Comment: @CodyGray Points 1-6 are obviously not hyperbole. I edited to clarify what I think the problem is. The OP edits just before the final close vote and the question never enters the re-open queue.

Comment: Question is now purely about a specific site malfunction which wasn't obvious to me when I first posted. This is a separate issue. Stack doesn't want to help you formulate a better question. The system results in expecting it to be perfect when you posted it. There were 2 downvotes before I edited it to be extremely specific. Now 4. Confirmation bias is real. Showing up/downvotes to unanswered questions = bad idea.

Comment: @xendi You're still making assumptions about the motivations of the downvoters, which is part of the reason you got those downvotes in the first place.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Are you suggesting that we shouldn't assume people using this site are ever prone to biases? Then you will wind up with self-perpetuating biases. Anyway, that has little to do with the problem I outlined. I'll even remove the bit about biases. It won't matter.

Comment: @xendi I'm saying you shouldn't assume that they *are* biased either. Just because you think the question is good after editing doesn't mean other people can't disagree.

Comment: Okay, I got rid of everything about bias. The question is about to be closed anyway, proving the whole point of this question @JohnMontgomery. It's perfect.

Comment: @xendi You didn't prove anything. I can't speak for the other voters, but I downvoted this question because I disagree with the premise and I voted to close it because it isn't clear what feature you're actually requesting. No biases involved.

Comment: @xendi you marked question **feature-request** yourself. I don't see how someone could have forced you to do so... And now you complain that people express disagreement with need for this feature by casting votes *as you requested*. I'm not sure what point it proves, but...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov, no. It's now a completely different question/request. There are close votes and downvotes that don't pertain to the content anymore. I started knowing there was some problem. Then, through this answer and comments, found the cause and updated the feature request to be accurate. All that matters now though is the group's initial opinion, which has nothing to do with the actual problem outlined in the question. How could it? It's completely changed but now it's some weird opinionated confirmation via voting that helps nothing and no-one. The system has flaws.

Comment: What happened to those downvoters that voted before I completely changed everything? Where are those 2 close voters? Almost no-one ever changes their votes after edits. Let's not fool ourselves into believing that.

Comment: @xendi I don't see your point... You posted "feature-request". As it stands currently it is very unclear what you propose to start with, but in general it does not look like a useful area to fix. It is *your* responsibility as the feature author to provide a solid reasoning for the feature to exist - i.e. digging throw SEDE to collect prove to presumed "there 1million questions that are edited last time 1 minute before the last close vote" and adding that information (including the query you come up with) to the post.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ugh. This site is filled with ironic problems. Yet another in that you posted that comment after the question had again been edited. I realized I had outlined a problem without suggesting a solution, which I now have added. Again, it won't matter as the group has spoken and no amount of edits matters. There are more problems than the close review queue which are exemplified by this page. It's the site's fault, not any one person's.

Comment: @xendi your proposed solution would fill up the review queues with trivial edits to questions from homework vamps, desperate to hand in someone else's work.  Yes, the site has problems, all sites have.  The trick is to only fix problems when the effort is justified AND the fix does not make the overall site experience worse:(

Answer (score 5):

I think the problem you're concerned about isn't actually happening.

> It was edited to be made good and still it's closed, where it will
> remain. I think the same problem happened in that case too, that it
> didn't make it into the queue because I started editing it before it
> was closed.

There's an [entry on the timeline for reopen](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/399666/timeline#review_26951) right above the one for your edit. It did enter the queue and got three Leave Closed votes. So there isn't a bug with posts not entering the queue.

The hypothetical in your question, where the OP does the edit before the third close vote, is possible but that isn't something that should change.

First, it's likely that if it got a 3rd close vote that whatever edits happened aren't sufficient. It would actually be unfair to the OP for their question to go through the queue before they had a chance to see someone said it still had issues and fix it just because the close vote happened within [n] minutes of the edit.

Second, I'm not convinced this wouldn't work (assuming the question is actually OK):

> If I were to edit it again to enter the queue, the reviewers will not
> see the relevant changes that were made. Say, if I were to add a
> period or anything just to get it into the queue. It won't be obvious
> that I had done anything meaningful.

There are two types of posts that show up in the Reopen Queue: posts that have been edited for the first type since being closed and posts that have a reopen vote on them. There are posts in the queue that have no edits to them whatsoever. So a post having little to no change isn't an indication that it shouldn't be reopened.

Furthermore, bigger edits aren't necessarily better. I don't go into the Reopen Queue much but I've seen posts that askers made *worse* after closure because they opted to remove a bunch of information that was needed or added way too much code or otherwise misunderstood or ignored the guidance of how they should be fixing their question.

Third, all users have the option of asking a question on Meta about their question on the main site. You can always ask for help addressing the issue in the close reason if you can't see any more edits to make and don't want to try just bumping it into the queue.

So I don't think pushing questions into the reopen queue based on what happens *before* closure is a good idea.